# Why is filling up at the gas pump require a quick scan of the Credit/Debit card?

Tags: credit-card

Always wondered about this. I had a friend tell me it's to make sure your information can't be stolen as easily on the credit card, but I will admit I am a bit skeptical of his claims.

At most gas pumps (as long as you dont pay with the attendant), the gas station usually requires you to insert your card, then just as quickly, "remove the card quickly". I've always wondered what would happen if you decided to leave your card in there, and sit there.

Why do the machines require you to remove the card quickly? Is this some security issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way the magnetic stripe reader works is by [detecting changes in the magnetic field of the stripe](http://andrewmohawk.com/2012/05/29/magnetic-stripes-part-1/) as it passes under/across the head, similar to a [magnetic tape head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_head).  In fact, mag stripes were invented from magnetic tape.  Just like swiping your card at a point-of-sale kiosk, removing the card "quickly" is necessary to read the magnetic field flipping.  (There's a certain minimum rate for the flips to be properly detected, but it varies from reader design to reader design.)  Feel free to leave the card in there, but it just won't be read by the pump.

Comment: Also, prompting the user to remove the card immediately reduces the number of cards that get left behind in the pump.  Same reason the ATM gives your card back first, and then gives you your money.

Answer (score 2):

They do it because the magnetic strip is read on the removal instead of on insert, and when you remove the card in one rapid motion, it assures a relatively constant reading speed that is least prone to misreads.

Comment: Actually, they typically read on insert and removal, and this gives them a good error resistance.